# Asus laptop doesn't turn on

Tags: laptop, power-supply, power, asus-laptop

My girlfriend has an Asus laptop with a battery that dosen't work, so she uses it while it's connected to the wall.

This laptop has been in use for 2 years+ I think, and today suddenly, it stoped working.
there are a few LED lights that still light up, but that's it. Other then that, the screen is black,
and nothing works.

I searched the web for solutions and tried something, that seem to work for a lot of people.

1.unplug battery (that easy, it doesn't have one).

2.take out the charger cord.

3.hold power button for 30 second.

3.insert power cord.

4.power up the laptop.

That didn't work for me.

I made a video of the lights that still work, when I turn on the machine.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6r4mWA0z67A&feature=youtu.be

I should add,that some of the noises that we used to hear when the machine was started are gone.
Could it be that it just died?

Any idea what happened?

Comment: It looks to me that your laptopscreen is broken. Maybe you could use an external monitor to test that?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things we can try here:

1. Unplug the AC cable and ensure the laptop is powered off
2. Remove the RAM from the system (usually accessible from the underside of the laptop)
3. With the RAM removed, plug the AC Cable back in and power on the system.

Put your ear to the system and see if you hear any noises or if anything is spinning. Let it sit for about 30 seconds and see if you hear any beeps coming from the computer as well. Then, you can try the following:

1. Place only 1 of your RAM sticks back into the DIMM slots on the underside of the laptop and see if the PC will boot.. You may have to try each of the DIMM slots with each of the sticks 1 at a time as it is possible the problem is being caused by a RAM stick or bad DIMM slot.
2. If you have an external monitor laying around and are able to connect it to your laptop, do so. It is possible that the back-light on the monitor has died and your PC is, in-fact, turning on, but not displaying.

If none of the above worked, it looks like the laptop has finally died and there isn't much more than can be done. Repairing a bad board on a laptop isn't really worth it as, even if it fixes the problem now, there will usually be more problems later on the down the road.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem with an ASUS laptop, because an Intel driver was broken (the patch was never released). I fixed it by installing Windows 8, then upgrading to 10 : the correct driver is kept during the upgrade.